# Passing all Enum values in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, enums

I have to pass an array of an enum as a function parameter, most of the time I have to pass every single case of the enum. Is there a shorthand way to include all instead of having to pass `[.NFL, .NBA, .NHL, .MLB, .NCAAM, .NCAAF]` every time? Can I make and all property so that I can just pass `.all` that included all the cases?

```
enum LSLeague: String {
    case NFL = "NFL"
    case NBA = "NBA"
    case NHL = "NHL"
    case MLB = "MLB"
    case NCAAM = "NCAAM"
    case NCAAF = "NCAAF"
}
```

Comment: No need for `rawValue`s in this case

Comment: It is Swift naming convention to name all your enumeration cases starting with a lowercase letter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use .allCases on the enum type.

So, you might still have to do a bit of work depending on your use case, but you can iterate over each element in an enum if you use:

```
    for league in LSLeague.allCases {
       //code here
    }
```

EDIT: @aheze had a great point that I just wanted to add into this answer. He says, "Make sure to also conform the enum to CaseIterable"

So, also make sure that you change the enum you have to:

```
    enum LSLeague: String: CaseIterable {
        case NFL = "NFL"
        case NBA = "NBA"
        case NHL = "NHL"
        case MLB = "MLB"
        case NCAAM = "NCAAM"
        case NCAAF = "NCAAF"
    }
```

if you're able to use this technique.

Comment: Make sure to also conform the enum to `CaseIterable`

Comment: Using ```LSLeague.allCases``` was the exact thing I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 5**

**Use CaseIterable protocol to the enum:**

```
enum CustomTypes: String, CaseIterable {
    case location = "Location"
    case organization = "Organization"
    case dutyUse = "Duty Use"
}
```

**Usage:**

```
let values: [String] = CustomTypes.allCases.map { $0.rawValue }
```

// values = ["Location", "Organization", "Duty Use"]

Comment: allCases.map solved my problem, and I have the different languages so It was also suitable for me. I will share my answer also here.

Answer (score -1):

**Swift 5**
(This Solution is for the multiple language, I am using this in live application.)

as per answer of **Prashant Gaikwad**, we need to use the CaseIterable protocol to the enum:

```
enum PlateType: String, CaseIterable {
    case classic
    case private

var engTitle: String {
    switch self {
    case .classic:
        return "Classic"
    case .privat:
        return "Private"
    }
}

//make title
var arbTitle: String {
    switch self {
    case .classic:
        return "كلاسيكية"
    case .privat:
        return "سيارة خاصة"
}
}
```

Now as per our use we will search like this for both languages. Here type contains our value that will be classic or private now we will use the code below like this

```
let selectedValue = PlateType.allCases.first(where: { $0.engTitle == type || $0.arbTitle == type })
```

"`type`" is the String value and that value can be in English or Arabic. Now print the value, as below code, you will get the value perfectly.

```
print(selectedValue)
```

this will show the value in the String.